# Which superhero/villain is this?

Tags: character-identification

Was hoping someone can tell me the name of this superhero/villian.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Apocalypse](http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse), also know as En Sabah Nur. He is an ancient mutant with an apocalyptic survival of the fittest agenda and a major recurring villain in the X-men franchise and some of its various spinoffs.

He is both a super powerful mutant and further enhanced by celestial technology. Like many major villains he never seems to actually get defeated for good.

He is the primary antagonist in the X-Men: Apocalypse film, and is played by Oscar Isaac.

Answer (score 4):

It's the God from [X-Men Apocalypse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3385516/). He's a mutant and a world destroyer.

The character name is [Apocalypse](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0001159/?ref_=tt_cl_t5) and is played by Oscar Isaac.

Comment: En Sabah Nur is his other in universe name, he is played by Oscar Isaac in the film.